# React infinite scroll component performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written the following infinite scroll component in React:

```
import React from 'react'
import { uniqueId, isUndefined, hasVerticalScrollbar, hasHorizontalScrollbar, isInt, throttle } from '../../../js/utils';

export default class BlSimpleInfiniteScroll extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)

        this.itemsIdsRefsMap = {}

        this.isLoading = false

        this.node = React.createRef()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {
            initialId
        } = this.props
        let id
        if (initialId) {
            if (typeof initialId === "function") {
                id = initialId()
            }
            else {
                id = initialId
            }
            this.scrollToId(id)   
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (
            this.isLoading
            &&
            prevProps.isInfiniteLoading
            &&
            !this.props.isInfiniteLoading
        ) {
            const axis = this.axis()
            const scrollProperty = this.scrollProperty(axis)
            const offsetProperty = this.offsetProperty(axis)
            this.scrollTo(scrollProperty, this.node.current[offsetProperty])
            this.isLoading = false
        }
    }

    itemsRenderer(items) {
        const length = items.length

        let i = 0
        const renderedItems = []
        for (const item of items) {
            renderedItems[i] = this.itemRenderer(item.id, i, length)
            i++
        }
        return renderedItems
    }

    itemRenderer(id, i, length) {
        const {
            itemRenderer,
            isInfiniteLoading,
            displayInverse
        } = this.props

        let renderedItem = itemRenderer(id, i)
        if (isInfiniteLoading) {
            if (!displayInverse && (i == length - 1)) {
                renderedItem = this.standardLoadingComponentWrapperRenderer(id, renderedItem)
            }
            else if (i == 0) {
                renderedItem = this.inverseLoadingComponentWrapperRenderer(id, renderedItem)
            }
        }
        const ref = this.itemsIdsRefsMap[id] || (this.itemsIdsRefsMap[id] = React.createRef())
        return (
            <div className="bl-simple-infinite-scroll-item"
                key={id}
                ref={ref}>
                {renderedItem}
            </div>
        )
    }

    loadingComponentRenderer() {
        const {
            loadingComponent
        } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="bl-simple-infinite-scroll-loading-component"
                key={uniqueId()}>
                {loadingComponent}
            </div>
        )
    }

    loadingComponentWrapperRenderer(id, children) {
        return (
            <div className="bl-simple-infinite-scroll-loading-component-wrapper"
                key={id}>
                {children}
            </div>
        )
    }

    standardLoadingComponentWrapperRenderer(id, renderedItem) {
        return this.loadingComponentWrapperRenderer(id, [
            renderedItem,
            this.loadingComponentRenderer()
        ])
    }

    inverseLoadingComponentWrapperRenderer(id, renderedItem) {
        return this.loadingComponentWrapperRenderer(id, [
            this.loadingComponentRenderer(),
            renderedItem
        ])
    }

    axis() {
        return this.props.axis === 'x' ? 'x' : 'y'
    }

    scrollProperty(axis) {
        return axis == 'y' ? 'scrollTop' : 'scrollLeft'
    }

    offsetProperty(axis) {
        return axis == 'y' ? 'offsetHeight' : 'offsetWidth'
    }

    scrollDimProperty(axis) {
        return axis == 'y' ? 'scrollHeight' : 'scrollWidth'
    }

    hasScrollbarFunction(axis) {
        return axis == 'y' ? hasVerticalScrollbar : hasHorizontalScrollbar
    }

    scrollToStart() {
        const axis = this.axis()
        this.scrollTo(
            this.scrollProperty(axis),
            !this.props.displayInverse ?
                0
                :
                this.scrollDimProperty(axis)
        )
    }

    scrollToEnd() {
        const axis = this.axis()
        this.scrollTo(
            this.scrollProperty(axis),
            !this.props.displayInverse ?
                this.scrollDimProperty(axis)
                :
                0
        )
    }

    scrollTo(scrollProperty, scrollPositionOrPropertyOfScrollable) {
        const scrollableContentNode = this.node.current
        if (scrollableContentNode) {
            scrollableContentNode[scrollProperty] = isInt(scrollPositionOrPropertyOfScrollable) ?
                scrollPositionOrPropertyOfScrollable
                :
                scrollableContentNode[scrollPositionOrPropertyOfScrollable]
        }
    }

    scrollToId(id) {
        if (this.itemsIdsRefsMap[id] && this.itemsIdsRefsMap[id].current) {
            this.itemsIdsRefsMap[id].current.scrollIntoView()
        }
    }

    handleScroll() {
        const {
            isInfiniteLoading,
            infiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset,
            displayInverse
        } = this.props
        if (
            this.props.onInfiniteLoad
            &&
            !isInfiniteLoading
            &&
            this.node.current
            &&
            !this.isLoading
        ) {
            const axis = this.axis()
            const scrollableContentNode = this.node.current
            const scrollProperty = this.scrollProperty(axis)
            const offsetProperty = this.offsetProperty(axis)
            const scrollDimProperty = this.scrollDimProperty(axis)
            const currentScroll = scrollableContentNode[scrollProperty]
            const currentDim = scrollableContentNode[offsetProperty]
            const scrollDim = scrollableContentNode[scrollDimProperty]

            const finalInfiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset = !isUndefined(infiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset) ?
                infiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset
                :
                currentDim / 2

            let thresoldWasReached = false
            let memorizeLastElementBeforeInfiniteLoad = () => { }
            if (!displayInverse) {
                thresoldWasReached = currentScroll >= (scrollDim - finalInfiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset)
            }
            else {
                memorizeLastElementBeforeInfiniteLoad = () => {
                    // TODO
                }
                thresoldWasReached = currentScroll <= finalInfiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset
            }
            if (thresoldWasReached) {
                this.isLoading = true
                memorizeLastElementBeforeInfiniteLoad()
                this.props.onInfiniteLoad()
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {
            items
        } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="bl-simple-infinite-scroll"
                ref={this.node}
                onScroll={this.handleScroll}
                onMouseOver={this.props.onInfiniteScrollMouseOver}
                onMouseOut={this.props.onInfiniteScrollMouseOut}
                onMouseEnter={this.props.onInfiniteScrollMouseEnter}
                onMouseLeave={this.props.onInfiniteScrollMouseLeave}>
                {this.itemsRenderer(items)}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

And I use it like this in a chat app I am writing:

```
...
<BlSimpleInfiniteScroll items={chat.messages}
    ref={this.infiniteScrollComponentRef}
    initialId={() => lastOfArray(chat.messages).id}
    itemRenderer={(id, i) => this.messageRenderer(id, i, chat.messages)}
    loadingComponent={<BlLoadingSpinnerContainer />}
    isInfiniteLoading={isChatLoading}
    displayInverse
    infiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset={void 0}
    infiniteLoadingBeginBottomOffset={void 0}
    onInfiniteLoad={() => this.props.onLoadPreviousChatMessages(chat.id)}
    onInfiniteScrollMouseEnter={this.handleInfiniteScrollMouseEnter}
    onInfiniteScrollMouseLeave={this.handleInfiniteScrollMouseLeave} />
...
```

The problem is that as soon as I scroll until the thresold and `onInfiniteLoad` is called, before the loading spinner is showed and after the data has been loaded the scroll freezes and the component becomes unresponsive.
How can I resolve this issue?
When I render the spinner container and after the previous loaded messages, shouldn't React just append the new divs retaining the previously added items in order to maintain the component performant?
If not, what key concepts of React I am missing?

Thank you for your attention!

**UPDATE**: Here are the additional components:

`BlOrderChat` represents a chat window and renders `BlSimpleInfiniteScroll`:

```
import React from 'react'
import BlOrderChatMessage from './BlOrderChatMessage';
import { isEmpty, uniqueId } from '../../../js/utils';
import { chatSelector } from '../selectors';
import BlLoadingSpinnerContainer from '../../core/animation/loading/BlLoadingSpinnerContainer';
import BlSimpleInfiniteScroll from '../../core/scroll/BlSimpleInfiniteScroll';

export default class BlOrderChat extends React.Component {

    static BL_ORDER_CHAT_MESSAGE_ID_ATTR_PREFIX = 'blOrderChatMessage'

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.messageRenderer = this.messageRenderer.bind(this)

        this.infiniteScrollComponentRef = React.createRef()
    }

    scrollToBottom() {
        this.infiniteScrollComponentRef.current && this.infiniteScrollComponentRef.current.scrollToStart()
    }

    messageRenderer(messageId, index, messages) {
        const {
            currentUser, chat
        } = this.props
        const message = messages[index]
        const length = messages.length
        const fromUser = chat.users.items[message.from_user_id]

        const itemComponentRender = (children) => (
            <div key={messageId}>
                {children}
            </div>
        )

        const messageIdAttr = `${BlOrderChat.BL_ORDER_CHAT_MESSAGE_ID_ATTR_PREFIX}${message.id}`
        const renderMessageComponent = () => (
            <BlOrderChatMessage id={messageIdAttr}
                key={uniqueId() + message.id}
                message={message.message}
                sentUnixTs={message.sent_unix_ts}
                currentUser={currentUser}
                fromUser={fromUser}
                usersInvolvedInChatLength={chat.users.order.length} />
        )
        let children = []
        if (index === 0) {
            // First message.
            children = [
                <div key={uniqueId()} className="bl-padding"></div>,
                renderMessageComponent()
            ]
        }
        else if (index === length - 1) {
            // Last message.
            children = [
                renderMessageComponent(onComponentDidMount),
                <div key={uniqueId()} className="bl-padding"></div>
            ]
        }
        else {
            // Message in the middle.
            children = [
                renderMessageComponent()
            ]
        }
        return itemComponentRender(children)
    }

    render() {
        const {
            chat: propsChat, isChatLoading,
            currentUser
        } = this.props

        const chat = chatSelector(propsChat, currentUser)
        const chatHasMessages = chat && !isEmpty(chat.messages)

        return (
            <div className="bl-order-chat">
                <div className="bl-order-chat-header">
                    // ...
                </div>
                <div className="bl-order-chat-content">
                    {
                        (chatHasMessages &&
                            <div className="bl-order-chat-content-inner">
                                <div className="bl-order-chat-infinite-scroll">
                                    <BlSimpleInfiniteScroll items={chat.messages}
                                        ref={this.infiniteScrollComponentRef}
                                        initialId={() => lastOfArray(chat.messages).id}
                                        itemRenderer={(id, i) => this.messageRenderer(id, i, chat.messages)}
                                        loadingComponent={<BlLoadingSpinnerContainer />}
                                        isInfiniteLoading={isChatLoading}
                                        displayInverse
                                        infiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset={void 0}
                                        infiniteLoadingBeginBottomOffset={void 0}
                                        onInfiniteLoad={() => this.props.onLoadPreviousChatMessages(chat.id)}
                                        onInfiniteScrollMouseEnter={this.handleInfiniteScrollMouseEnter}
                                        onInfiniteScrollMouseLeave={this.handleInfiniteScrollMouseLeave} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                        ||
                        (isChatLoading &&
                            <BlLoadingSpinnerContainer />
                        )
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="bl-order-chat-footer">
                    // ...
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`BlOrderChatBox`, contains `BlOrderChat`:

```
import React from 'react'
import BlOrderChat from './BlOrderChat';
import BlAlert from '../../core/alert/BlAlert';
import BlLoadingSpinnerContainer from '../../core/animation/loading/BlLoadingSpinnerContainer';

export default class BlOrderChatBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.node = React.createRef()
    }

    render() {
        const {
            ordId, currentChat,
            isCurrentChatLoading, currentUser,
            err
        } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="bl-order-chat-box" ref={this.node}>
                <div className="bl-order-chat-box-inner">
                    {
                        (err &&
                            <BlAlert type="error" message={err} />)
                        ||
                        (currentChat && (
                            // ...
                            <div className="bl-order-chat-box-inner-chat-content">
                                <BlOrderChat ordId={ordId}
                                    chat={currentChat}
                                    isChatLoading={isCurrentChatLoading}
                                    onLoadPreviousChatMessages={this.props.onLoadPreviousChatMessages}
                                    currentUser={currentUser} />
                            </div>
                        ))
                        ||
                        <BlLoadingSpinnerContainer />
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

And here is the component which renders `BlOrderChatBox` (it is the topmost stateful component):

```
import React from 'react'
import { POSTJSON } from '../../../js/ajax';
import config from '../../../config/config';
import { newEmptyArrayAble, arrayToArrayAbleItemsOrder, arrayAbleItemsOrderToArray, mergeArrayAbles, newArrayAble, firstOfArrayAble, isArrayAble } from '../../../js/data_structures/arrayable';

export default class BlOrderChatApp extends React.Component {

    static NEW_CHAT_ID = 0

    static MAX_NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_LOAD_PER_AJAX = 30

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.currentUser = globals.USER
        this.lastHandleSendMessagePromise = Promise.resolve()
        this.newMessagesMap = {}
        this.typingUsersDebouncedMap = {}

        // Imagine this comes from a database.
        const chat = {
            // ...
        }

        const initialState = {
            chats: newArrayAble(this.newChat(chat)),
            currentChatId: null,
            shouldSelectUserForNewChat: false,
            newChatReceivingUsers: newEmptyArrayAble(),
            isChatListLoading: false,
            isCurrentChatLoading: false,
            popoverIsOpen: false,
            popoverHasOpened: false,
            err: void 0,
            focusSendMessageTextarea: false,
            newChatsIdsMap: {},
            currentChatAuthActs: {},
            BlOrderChatComponent: null,
        }
        this.state = initialState

        this.handleLoadPreviousChatMessages = this.handleLoadPreviousChatMessages.bind(this)
    }

    POST(jsonData, callback) {
        let requestJSONData
        if (typeof jsonData === "string") {
            requestJSONData = {
                action: jsonData
            }
        }
        else {
            requestJSONData = jsonData
        }
        return POSTJSON(config.ORDER_CHAT_ENDPOINT_URI, {
            ...requestJSONData,
            order_chat_type: this.props.orderChatType,
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
            this.POSTResponseData(json, callback)
        })
    }

    POSTResponseData(data, callback) {
        if (data.err) {
            this.setState({
                err: data.err
            })
        }
        else {
            callback && callback(data)
        }
    }

    newChat(chat) {
        const newChat = {
            id: (chat && chat.id) || BlOrderChatApp.NEW_CHAT_ID,
            ord_id: this.props.ordId,
            users: (chat && chat.users && (isArrayAble(chat.users) ? chat.users : arrayToArrayAbleItemsOrder(chat.users))) || newEmptyArrayAble(),
            messages: (chat && chat.messages && (isArrayAble(chat.messages) ? chat.messages : arrayToArrayAbleItemsOrder(chat.messages))) || newEmptyArrayAble(),
            first_message_id: (chat && chat.first_message_id) || null,
            typing_users_ids_map: (chat && chat.typing_users_ids_map) || {},
        }
        return newChat
    }

    isChatNew(chat) {
        return (
            chat
            &&
            (chat.id == BlOrderChatApp.NEW_CHAT_ID || this.state.newChatsIdsMap[chat.id])
        )
    }

    loadPreviousChatMessages(chatId, lowestMessageIdOrNull, makeChatIdCurrent) {
        this.POST({
            act: 'loadPreviousChatMessages',
            chat_id: chatId,
            lowest_message_id: lowestMessageIdOrNull,
            max_number_of_messages_to_load: BlOrderChatApp.MAX_NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_LOAD_PER_AJAX
        }, json => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                const chat = prevState.chats.items[chatId]
                const messages = arrayToArrayAbleItemsOrder(json.messages)

                const newChat = {
                    ...chat,
                    messages: mergeArrayAbles(messages, chat.messages)
                }
                const chats = mergeArrayAbles(prevState.chats, newArrayAble(newChat))
                return {
                    ...(makeChatIdCurrent ?
                        {
                            currentChatId: chatId,
                            focusSendMessageTextarea: true,
                        }
                        :
                        {
                            currentChatId: prevState.currentChatId,
                        }
                    ),
                    chats,
                    isCurrentChatLoading: false,
                }
            })
        })
    }

    loadPreviousChatMessagesIfNotAllLoaded(chatId) {
        let lowestMessageIdOrNull
        const chat = this.state.chats.items[chatId]
        if (
            !this.isChatNew(chat)
            &&
            (lowestMessageIdOrNull = (chat.messages.order.length && firstOfArrayAble(chat.messages).id) || null)
            &&
            lowestMessageIdOrNull != chat.first_message_id
        ) {
            this.setState({
                isCurrentChatLoading: true
            }, () => {
                this.loadPreviousChatMessages(chat.id, lowestMessageIdOrNull)
            })
        }
    }

    handleLoadPreviousChatMessages(chatId) {
        this.loadPreviousChatMessagesIfNotAllLoaded(chatId)
    }

    // ...

    render() {
        const currentChat = this.state.chats.items[this.state.currentChatId] || null
        const err = this.state.err

        return (
            <div className="bl-order-chat-app">
                <BlOrderChatBox currentUser={this.currentUser}
                    chats={arrayAbleItemsOrderToArray(this.state.chats)}
                    currentChat={currentChat}
                    isCurrentChatLoading={this.state.isCurrentChatLoading}
                    onLoadPreviousChatMessages={this.handleLoadPreviousChatMessages}
                    err={err} />
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

I tried to remove all the irrelevant code to simplify the reading. Also here is the file which contains the `chatSelector` function (normalizes the chat array-able object) and the `*ArrayAble*` functions (an array-able object to me is basically an object which maps objects through their ids in `items` and has an `order` property which keeps the sort):

```
import { isUndefined, unshiftArray, findIndex } from "../utils";

export function chatSelector(chat, currentUser) {
    const newChat = { ...chat }
    newChat.messages = arrayAbleItemsOrderToArray(chat.messages).sort((a, b) => {
        const sortByUnixTs = a.sent_unix_ts - b.sent_unix_ts
        if (sortByUnixTs == 0) {
            return a.id - b.id
        }
        return sortByUnixTs
    })
    newChat.users = arrayAbleItemsOrderToArray(chat.users).filter(user => user.id != currentUser.id)
    return newChat
}

/**
 * Given an array-able object, returns its array representation using an order property.
 * This function acts as a selector function.
 * 
 * The array-able object MUST have the following shape:
 * 
 *      {
 *          items: {},
 *          order: []
 *      }
 * 
 * Where "items" is the object containing the elements of the array mapped by values found in "order"
 * in order.
 * 
 * @see https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-why-you-should-use-an-object-not-an-array-for-lists-bee4a1fbc8bd
 * @see https://medium.com/@antonytuft/maybe-you-would-do-something-like-this-a1ab7f436808
 * 
 * @param {Object} obj An object.
 * @param {Object} obj.items The items of the object mapped by keys.
 * @param {Array} obj.order The ordered keys.
 * @return {Array} The ordered array representation of the given object.
 */
export function arrayAbleItemsOrderToArray(obj) {
    const ret = []
    for (const key of obj.order) {
        if (!isUndefined(obj.items[key])) {
            ret[ret.length] = obj.items[key]
        }
    }
    return ret
}

export function arrayToArrayAbleItemsOrder(array, keyProp = "id") {
    const obj = newEmptyArrayAble()
    for (const elem of array) {
        const key = elem[keyProp]
        obj.items[key] = elem
        obj.order[obj.order.length] = key
    }
    return obj
}

export function newEmptyArrayAble() {
    return {
        items: {},
        order: []
    }
}

export function isEmptyArrayAble(arrayAbleObj) {
    return !arrayAbleObj.order.length
}

export function mergeArrayAbles(arrayAbleObj1, arrayAbleObj2, prependObj2 = false) {
    const obj = newEmptyArrayAble()
    for (const key of arrayAbleObj1.order) {
        if (isUndefined(arrayAbleObj1.items[key])) {
            continue
        }
        obj.items[key] = arrayAbleObj1.items[key]
        obj.order[obj.order.length] = key
    }
    for (const key of arrayAbleObj2.order) {
        if (isUndefined(arrayAbleObj2.items[key])) {
            continue
        }
        if (!(key in obj.items)) {
            if (!prependObj2) {
                // Default.
                obj.order[obj.order.length] = key
            }
            else {
                unshiftArray(obj.order, key)
            }
        }
        obj.items[key] = arrayAbleObj2.items[key]
    }
    return obj
}

export function newArrayAble(initialItem = void 0, keyProp = "id") {
    const arrayAble = newEmptyArrayAble()
    if (initialItem) {
        arrayAble.items[initialItem[keyProp]] = initialItem
        arrayAble.order[arrayAble.order.length] = initialItem[keyProp]
    }
    return arrayAble
}

export function lastOfArrayAble(obj) {
    return (
        (
            obj.order.length
            &&
            obj.items[obj.order[obj.order.length - 1]]
        )
        ||
        void 0
    )
}
```

Thank you for your help. If there's something missing which I should have included, please, let me know!

**UPDATE**: Thanks to **Sultan H.** it has improved, though the scroll still blocks as soon as I get the reply from the server. See it here: https://streamable.com/3nzu0
Any idea on how to improve this behaviour further?

Thanks!

Comment: can you include `onLoadPreviousChatMessages` function in your question, wanna be able to understand what it really does. if there was chain of other components called inside of it, please try to add them too.

The problem might not be on that component.

Comment: OK, I will do it asap this afternoon and update my question!

Comment: I'll try to be here to support.

Comment: I updated my question!

Comment: I am reading through the code and hoping to get exactly where the load happens.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to resolve the performance issue, it's not preferrable to do tasks inside the Arrow Function that calculates the new state, in this case, at `loadPreviousChatMessages` you are calculating stuff in the callback, which may yeild to a load while setting the state on that context.

Preferrable Changes, replace `this.setState` inside your function with this code, all I've done here is clear the context by moving all the tasks out:

```
            const chat = this.state.chats.items[chatId];
            const messages = arrayToArrayAbleItemsOrder(json.messages);
            const newChat = {
              ...chat,
              messages: mergeArrayAbles(messages, chat.messages);
            }
            const chats = mergeArrayAbles(prevState.chats, newArrayAble(newChat));
            const newState = {
              ...(
                makeChatIdCurrent ?
                  {
                      currentChatId: chatId,
                      focusSendMessageTextarea: true,
                  }
                  :
                  {
                      currentChatId: this.state.currentChatId,
                  }
              ),
              chats,
              isCurrentChatLoading: false,
            };

            this.setState(() => newState);
```

If that doesn't entirely solve the issue, can you tell if there was at least an improvment?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, it has improved a bit. My concern with this approach is that I will lose some of the messages if I update the state this way. Beside the loading of the previous messages, I have hooks which receive new messages from other users, therefore it can also happen that while the user is waiting for the previous messages, a new message arrives. How would React handle this situations? I read in the React documentation that using a callback with `setState` is the only reliable way to compute a new state from the current up to date state. What do you think?

Comment: First things first, Is performance issue loading older messages considered to be solved? and yes, you are correct, using the callback to update the state is the most guaranteed and reliable, but in this context it won't make a different, because we don't have consequence updates on the state, and the load function as to my guess will never occur twice before actually updating once, does this code, for now make the chat functionality broken for loading older messages?, if there wasn't problems with loading the older ones, then we shall discuss how you load the new ones!

Comment: It has improved, yes, though the scroll still blocks as soon as the JSON response is available in `json`. See it here -> https://streamable.com/3nzu0. The scroll jumps as I scroll down while new messages are being loaded. Regarding the new messages, they arrive from a WebSocket connection and are appended to the bottom instead of being prepended to the top (like the old ones). Wouldn't computing the new state outside of the `setState` callback lead to run conditions if e.g. I receive a new message from the WS connection and the AJAX returns the old ones almost at the same time?

Comment: Sorry tonix, I wanted to keep going on with it this night, apparently I exhausted myself today :lol: , I'll check back again.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your help, would be great to discuss this topic again with you. I will only tell you that I needed to wrap everything back within the `setState` updater callback because of this post on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996496/real-world-usage-of-setstate-with-an-updater-callback-instead-of-passing-an-obje/56996881. I need to guarantee that all messages will always be preserved in state and due to the asynchronicity of the app (AJAX, WebSockets), race conditions can happen. To improve performance I added the rendered components to the state of `BlOrderChatApp`.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds sticking to it, but, the post you have shared an the answer you considered doesn't in anywat conflict with the solution we have, HOW: what can make (asynch/synch)ronicity problem is passing an object to `setState` method, but still in the answer, we are passing a callback function that returns the new state object, which was actually made to solve the old setting object directly way.

Which assure that the change on the state will be immediate with no delay.

Comment: Affter reading the whole functionality again, specially after adding the `Arryable` functionality, it's almost natural for the scroll lagging behaviour to happen, there are some intense sudden load of tasks that is run in the browser synchronously, which has in it a significant number of loops coming from `*ArrayAble*` functions, the approach I suggest taking is trying to do this kind of work at the back-end instead of sending the transferable `ArrayAble`to the front-end and do the work in the browser, these kind of tasks in this order are naturally laggy.

Comment: OK, I will try to refactor then. The `arrayable` idea is from this article https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-why-you-should-use-an-object-not-an-array-for-lists-bee4a1fbc8bd . The author says they are better than standard arrays and I was thinking that it's worth giving them a try. What data structure you suggest for the messages of the chat, as you have seen I often need to append to it and also modify a particular message given its `id`. Using `array.map` doesn't seem a good idea too. The only thing I can think of is a linked hash map

Comment: Maybe an object will be enough, it will also be helpful tracking down messages with there ids instead of looping around to pick one, also, to render them would be same as doing it with array, such like `Object.values.map`.

It is a very wonderful Idea, I was impressed actually, but I can't see how this can be refactored using the same approach to fit with browser capabilities, you know that one little complix loop can boom boom the browser tab and kill the performance with a very hight footprint mark on the memory.

Comment: `Sorry if it sounds sticking to it, but, the post you have shared an the answer you considered doesn't in anywat conflict with the solution we have, ...` I am sorry, but I didn't understand your comment regarding the other post I linked you about `setState` updater function,

Comment: I think am losing my English tonight :D , I want you to go to this [link](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1) and read in Function in `setState` to the rescue! section of that article.

Comment: Thank you for the nice article! Now I reread your comment and I think I understand what you meant. The thing is that if we move the code within the `setState` updater function in the enclosing scope of `setState`, even if after we call `setState` with the updater function which *only* just returns the `new state object`, we are creating that `new state object` accessing `this.state`, and therefore there's no guarantee that at that moment `this.state` will be up to date. Don't you agree with my assumptions? Let me know what you think!