# Real world usage of setState with an updater callback instead of passing an object in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

The React documentation says the following about [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

`If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below`,

Beside the following sentence, which I don't understand:

> If mutable objects are being used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in **shouldComponentUpdate()**, calling **setState()** only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

They say:

> The first argument is an **updater** function with the signature *(state, props) => stateChange* ... **state** is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied.

And make an example:

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {counter: state.counter + props.step};
});
```

Saying:

> Both **state** and **props** received by the updater function are **guaranteed to be up-to-date**. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with state.

What do they mean by **guaranteed to be up-to-date** and what should we be aware of when deciding if we should use `setState` with an updater function `(state, props) => stateChange` or directly with an object as the first parameter?

Let's assume a real world scenario. Suppose we have a fancy chat application where:

1. The state of the chat is represented by `this.state = { messages: [] }`;
2. Previous messages are loaded making an AJAX request and are prepended to the `messages` currently in the state;
3. If other users (not the current user) send a message to the current user, new messages arrive to current user from a realtime WebSocket connection and are appended to the `messages` currently in the state;
4. If it is the current user the one who sends the message, the message is appended to the `messages` of the state as in point 3 as soon as the AJAX request fired when the message is sent completes;

Let's pretend this is our `FancyChat` component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class FancyChat extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            messages: []
        }

        this.API_URL = 'http://...'

        this.handleLoadPreviousChatMessages = this.handleLoadPreviousChatMessages.bind(this)
        this.handleNewMessageFromOtherUser = this.handleNewMessageFromOtherUser.bind(this)
        this.handleNewMessageFromCurrentUser = this.handleNewMessageFromCurrentUser.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Assume this is a valid WebSocket connection which lets you add hooks:
        this.webSocket = new FancyChatWebSocketConnection()
        this.webSocket.addHook('newMessageFromOtherUsers', this.handleNewMessageFromOtherUser)
    }

    handleLoadPreviousChatMessages() {
        // Assume `AJAX` lets you do AJAX requests to a server.
        AJAX(this.API_URL, {
            action: 'loadPreviousChatMessages',
            // Load a previous chunk of messages below the oldest message
            // which the client currently has or (`null`, initially) load the last chunk of messages.
            below_id: (this.state.messages && this.state.messages[0].id) || null
        }).then(json => {
            // Need to prepend messages to messages here.
            const messages = json.messages

            // Should we directly use an updater object:
            this.setState({ 
                messages: messages.concat(this.state.messages)
                    .sort(this.sortByTimestampComparator)
            })

            // Or an updater callback like below cause (though I do not understand it fully)
            // "Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date."?
            this.setState((state, props) => {
                return {
                    messages: messages.concat(state.messages)
                        .sort(this.sortByTimestampComparator)
                }
            })

            // What if while the user is loading the previous messages, it also receives a new message
            // from the WebSocket channel?
        })
    }

    handleNewMessageFromOtherUser(data) {
        // `message` comes from other user thanks to the WebSocket connection.
        const { message } = data

        // Need to append message to messages here.
        // Should we directly use an updater object:
        this.setState({ 
            messages: this.state.messages.concat([message])
                // Assume `sentTimestamp` is a centralized Unix timestamp computed on the server.
                .sort(this.sortByTimestampComparator)
        })

        // Or an updater callback like below cause (though I do not understand it fully)
        // "Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date."?
        this.setState((state, props) => {
            return {
                messages: state.messages.concat([message])
                    .sort(this.sortByTimestampComparator)
            }
        })
    }

    handleNewMessageFromCurrentUser(messageToSend) {
        AJAX(this.API_URL, {
            action: 'newMessageFromCurrentUser',
            message: messageToSend
        }).then(json => {
            // Need to append message to messages here (message has the server timestamp).
            const message = json.message

            // Should we directly use an updater object:
            this.setState({ 
                messages: this.state.messages.concat([message])
                    .sort(this.sortByTimestampComparator)
            })

            // Or an updater callback like below cause (though I do not understand it fully)
            // "Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date."?
            this.setState((state, props) => {
                return {
                    messages: state.messages.concat([message])
                        .sort(this.sortByTimestampComparator)
                }
            })

            // What if while the current user is sending a message it also receives a new one from other users?
        })
    }

    sortByTimestampComparator(messageA, messageB) {
        return messageA.sentTimestamp - messageB.sentTimestamp
    }

    render() {
        const {
            messages
        } = this.state

        // Here, `messages` are somehow rendered together with an input field for the current user,
        // as well as the above event handlers are passed further down to the respective components.
        return (
            <div>
                {/* ... */}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

With so many asynchronous operations, how can I be really sure that `this.state.messages` will always be consistent with the data on the server and how would I use `setState` for each case? What considerations I should make? Should I always use the `updater` function of `setState` (why?) or is safe to directly pass an object as the `updater` parameter (why?)?

Thank you for the attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is only concerned with *component* state consistency, not server/client consistency. So `setState` makes no guarantees that the component state is consistent with anything else.

The reason an updater function is provided, is because state updates are sometimes delayed, and don't occur immediately when `setState` is called. Therefore, without the updater function, you have essentially a race condition. For example:

- your component begins with `state = {counter: 0}`
- you have a button that updates the counter when clicked in the following way: `this.setState({counter: this.state.counter +1})`
- the user clicks the button really fast, so that the state does not have time to be updated between clicks.
- that means that the counter will only increase by one, instead of the expected 2 - assuming that counter was originally 0, both times the button is clicked, the call ends up being `this.setState({counter: 0+1})`, setting the state to 1 both times.

An updater function fixes this, because the updates are applied in order:

- your component begins with `state = {counter: 0}`
- you have a button that updates the counter when clicked in the following way: `this.setState((currentState, props) => ({counter: currentState.counter + 1}))`
- the user clicks the button really fast, so that the state does not have time to be updated between clicks.
- unlike the other way, `currentState.counter + 1` does not get evaluated immediately
- the first updater function is called with the initial state `{counter: 0}`, and sets the state to `{counter: 0+1}`
- the second updater function is called with the state `{counter: 1}`, and sets the state to `{counter: 1+1}`

Generally speaking, the updater function is the less error-prone way to change the state, and there is rarely a reason to not use it (although if you are setting a static value, you don't strictly need it).

What you care about, however, is that updates to the state don't cause improper data (duplicates and the like). In that case, I would take care that the updates are designed so that they are idempotent and work no matter the current state of the data. For instance, instead of using an array to keep the collection of messages, use a map instead, and store each message by key or hash that is unique to that message, no matter where it came from (a millisecond timestamp may be unique enough). Then, when you get the same data from two locations, it will not cause duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Two questions rise up. If `without the updater function, you have essentially a race condition`, when and why would you use `this.setState({ ... })` with an updater object at all? What about the example I made? You answer makes me think that I need to always and only use `setState` with an updater function in order to guarantee that there won't be race conditions and that I will not lose some updates. Imagine that the chat has 1000 users actively writing simultaneously, without using always an updater function, some messages won't even render...

Comment: aaKhan's answer has valid example of a case where an updater function is not needed: `this.setState({color:randomColor})`. His state update doesn't depend on the previous state.  When you are modifying the state based on the previous state, then yes, always use the updater function to prevent bugs.

Comment: Then I can say that in my chat app example I always need to use the updater function, right?

Comment: Also, look at state management tools such as [redux](http://redux.js.org) and [mobx](http://mobx.js).

Comment: Thanks, yes, starting to use redux is already on my TODO list!

Comment: Forgot to ask, what do they mean when they say `If mutable objects are being used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.`?

Comment: Basically, the less often you call setState, the fewer times render is needed. (Sometimes you might call it as a no-op, and that might cause a render anyway). Also, you can control if a render is needed (conditionally) by using the `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle method. See the react [PureRender](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) component as an example.

Comment: OK, but what are `mutable objects` in this case? Do they refer to objects of the component's state or the instances of React components?

Comment: The `mutable objects` referred to are either state or props (both `this.state` and `this.props` can be considered "state", but that can get confusing. They often behave similarly though.) - essentially, the data that is being rendered. If that data is __immutable__, then if an item is `===` to another item, then the data has not changed. But with __mutable__ data, an item can be `===` _and_ its data could have changed.

Comment: So the docs just warns us that if we use mutable data, we should strive to call setState only when we know that something has really changed under the hood?

Comment: Essentially. But the same is true with immutable data. It's just an easy `===` check for immutable data to determine what has changed. I would put it like this: calling set state can cause another render, which is expensive. Immutable state makes it easy to tell if that render is needed and skip it, but mutable state makes that more difficult. By default, react assumes your data is mutable, and re-renders on most set state calls. But if you don't call set state, react won't even try to re-render. So you can save some processing that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in React by any means and have only been doing it for two months only, but here's what I learned from my very first project in React, which was as simple as showing a random quote.

If you need to use the updated state right after you use setState, always use the updater function. Let me give you an example.

```
// 
 handleClick = () => {
   //get a random color
   const newColor = this.selectRandomColor();
   //Set the state to this new color
   this.setState({color:newColor});
   //Change the background or some elements color to this new Color
   this.changeBackgroundColor();
}
```

I did this and what happened was that the color that was set to the body was always the previous color and not the current color in the state, because as you know, the `setState` is batched. It happens when React thinks it's best to execute it. It's not executed immediately. So to solve this problem, all I have to do was pass `this.changeColor` as a second argument to setState. Because that ensured that the color I applied was kept up to date with the current state.

So to answer your question, in your case, since you're job is to display the message to the user as soon as a new message arrives, i.e use the UPDATED STATE, always use the updater function and not the object.

Comment: Good note, but the OP was asking more about the _updater_ function, and you are talking about the _callback_ function to `setState`. They are both function arguments, but subtly different. The updater argument is used to calculate a change in the state, and is called _while_ the state is being updated. The callback function is called _after_ all updates are complete, and is used to react to changes in state (but not change it).

Comment: As @GarrettMotzner noted, you are talking about the second parameter of `setState`, the callback invoked after the state updates. My question refers to the **first** parameter of `setState`, which can either be a function or an object.